# creatings wordpress plugins settings Menu upon activation

Tags: wordpress

Here I want to have upon activation of my wordpress plugins activation

Before Activation

```
Activate | Edit | Delete
```

After Activation

```
Settings | Edit | Delete
```

How can this be done in code to add this Menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use the following snippet of code to add new action links.   I found this elsewhere and modified as needed.

```
function my_plugin_admin_action_links($links, $file) {
    static $my_plugin;
    if (!$my_plugin) {
        $my_plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
    }
    if ($file == $my_plugin) {
        $settings_link = '<a href="options-general.php?page=my_admin">Settings</a>';
        array_unshift($links, $settings_link);
    }
    return $links;
}

add_filter('plugin_action_links', 'my_plugin_admin_action_links', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a filter for `plugin_action_links` that you can set specifically for your plugin to add action links for your plugin on the Plugins page

Check out these blogs for more detail:

- http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B$prefix%7Dplugin_action_links
- http://www.wpmods.com/adding-plugin-action-links/

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of links in plugin list.Taken from

http://atiblog.com/wordpress-plugin-development/

[image]

**Use the following code in your Class.**

For Type 1:

```
add_action( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename( FILE ),array($this,'plugin_links') );
function plugin_links( $links ) {
  $links = array_merge( array('' . __( 'Settings', 'textdomain' ) . ''), $links );  
return $links;
}
```

For Type 2 : use filter.

```
add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', array($this,'plugin_row_meta_links'), 10, 2 );
function plugin_row_meta_links( $links, $file ) {
 $base = plugin_basename( FILE );
    if ($file == $base ) {
        $new_links = array(
                'donate' => 'Donate',
                                'doc' => 'Documentation'
                );
    $links = array_merge( $links, $new_links );    }    
  return $links;
}
```